# How to upsert record from one db connection to another in postgres using dbeaver?

Tags: postgresql, insert, sql-update, insert-update, dbeaver

I have two connections in my dbeaver namely preproduction and postproduction. Both the database have a table called profiles.

I want to upsert data from my `postproduction.profiles` into `preproduction.profiles`

I tried using the import feature but it is not providing conditional insert

What is the correct way to do so?

(My preproduction.profiles already have some records that's why I need upsert)

Answer (score 0):

In DBeaver during export or import process you can change some settings params, one of them - replace method. This method has 3 values:

1. none
2. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
3. ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE

You can choose 2nd or 3rd for upsert.
For more detail information please visit these sites:

[DBeaver Data Import and Replace](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Data-Import-and-Replace/)

[PostgreSQL Upsert Using INSERT ON CONFLICT statement](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-upsert/)

[image]